# psycopg2: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required

Tags: python, postgresql, pycharm

```
(venv) C:\Cursos\Django\personas_django\sap>python -m pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for psycopg2, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
    Running setup.py install for psycopg2 ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Cursos\Django\personas_django\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Josefina Pelliza\\App
Data\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9z8d6fx3\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Josefina Pelliza\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9z8d6fx3\\psycopg2\\se
tup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'
"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Josefina Pelliza\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ke5p9x11\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --instal
l-headers 'C:\Cursos\Django\personas_django\venv\include\site\python3.9\psycopg2'
         cwd: C:\Users\Josefina Pelliza\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9z8d6fx3\psycopg2\
    Complete output (22 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\errorcodes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\extensions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\extras.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\pool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\sql.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\tz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\_ipaddress.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\_json.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\_lru_cache.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\_range.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    copying lib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\psycopg2
    running build_ext
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Cursos\Django\personas_django\venv\Scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"
'C:\\Users\\Josefina Pelliza\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9z8d6fx3\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Josefina Pelliza\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\p
ip-install-9z8d6fx3\\psycopg2\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(c
ompile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Josefina Pelliza\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ke5p9x11\install-record.txt' --single-version-exte
rnally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Cursos\Django\personas_django\venv\include\site\python3.9\psycopg2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please add a brief description of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Microsoft Build tool.
You can use this [link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)

This should solve your problem. If any issues, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Psycopg2 packages for Windows released in the version of 2.9.9. https://github.com/psycopg/psycopg2/issues/1628

For me the issue has been resolved by just updating psycopg2 in the `requirements.txt` file to this new version.

```
...
psycopg2==2.9.9    # or greater, linux/macos: psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
...
```

Then install the package:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```